# How To Secure Shared MySql User

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

We have a mySql user that have about 20 database and all of each database is for one site , and i know its not secure and i want secure it and the users hadn't any access to other users database . and i dont want to create a new mysql user for each users , is there any way to secure this databases with this condition ? 
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: This sounds contradictory. Are you saying you want a mysql user that can access each database but also cannot access each database?

Comment: yeah . . . i think its not possible . . . do you know other way to secure this databases ?

Comment: @Jim is correct, have did you imagine to secure other DB with same account?

Comment: Only way is to create separate account for all sites.

Comment: "I want a car but don't want a car. Help me drive"?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible, you have to create a user for each database access and give them corresponding rights. It's the only way.

Comment: Worth to note that concept of users in databases was created mainly to solve this issue, which OP want's to solve without using an already working one...